# How to create a barchart with average pricing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a bar chart to show the average pricing.

```py
avg_values = {}

for i in labels:
    valuesforlevel = values[levels_values['town']==i]
    avg = np.average(valuesforlevel)
    print("Average for level " + i + " is {:.0f}".format(avg))
    avg_values[i] = avg

plt.figure(1, figsize=(50,50))
barchart = plt.bar(list(avg_values.keys()), list(avg_values.values()), color='#d62728')

for i in range(len(barchart)):
    bar = barchart[i]
    x,y  = bar.get_xy()
    h = bar.get_height()
    plt.text(x,h,"{:.0f}".format(list(avg_values.values())[i]),fontsize=30)

plt.title('Resale price',fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('Resale price',fontsize=40)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=40,rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

After I have input the coding and print out the result, it does not show the average pricing.
I thought the coding was to create the bar chart and inserting the heading and label names.

Comment: You can call `plt.bar_label(barchart)` to show the desired values. Nowadays, the loop through the bars is only needed if you need something rather fancy.  Note that your code doesn't provide test data, making it rather hard for other people to quickly check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The data + example below demonstrates adding bar labels using `plt.bar_label(...)`.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Bars on some test data
bars = plt.bar(np.arange(4), np.random.randint(10_000, 20_000, size=(4,)))

#Could suffice with just plt.bar_label(bars)
plt.bar_label(
    bars,
    fontsize=9, color='tab:red', rotation=45,
    label_type='edge', padding=5, fmt=lambda v: int(round(v, -2))
)
```

Optional extra formatting:

```
#Remove spines and add axis labels
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(4, 3)
[plt.gca().spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ('top', 'right')]
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Title\n') #add \n to avoid bar labels
```